# What does "we're good as new" mean here?

Tags: expressions

Friends Help Each Other is a song for Daniel Tiger's Neighborhood.
There are two lines:

> And when I spilled the tea I didn't know what to do
> But then we cleaned it all up and we're good as new

Here, "we're good as new", does it mean "we are OK"?
Is it common to say "we're good as new" when bad things are fixed?

Comment: "Good as new" is typically used to describe an object that has been mended or cleaned after having been broken or soiled. It's sometimes used - amusingly but inaccurately - to describe a baby that has stopped crying.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-good-as-new

Answer (score 1):

“good as new” refers to an object/relationship returning to it’s original status, by fixing or repairing OR it could be not literally for example when a car is used but looks in great condition you can say the car is “good as new”